# missing defaultconnection@qsqldatabase@@2peadea

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm working on a project that uses a sqlite database.
When I run project from the qt creator, everything works fine, but when I run exe file, application reports an error.

> The procedure entry point defaultconnection@qsqldatabase@@2peadea
>   could not be located in the dynamic link library.

Do you know where the problem is?

- To get all needed libraries I run `windeployqt.exe`
- I've added `QT += core gui sql` in my project.
- In qt creator everything works without error.

In my program directory is:

```
.\D3Dcompiler_47.dll
.\libEGL.dll
.\libGLESV2.dll
.\myapp.deploy.cmd
.\myapp.exe
.\opengl32sw.dll
.\Qt5Core.dll
.\Qt5Gui.dll
.\Qt5Sql.dll
.\Qt5Svg.dll
.\Qt5Widgets.dll

.\iconengines\qsvgicon.dll

.\imageformats\qgif.dll
.\imageformats\qicns.dll
.\imageformats\qico.dll
.\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
.\imageformats\qsvg.dll
.\imageformats\qtga.dll
.\imageformats\qtiff.dll
.\imageformats\qwbmp.dll
.\imageformats\qwebp.dll

.\platforms\qwindows.dll

.\sqldrivers\qsqlite.dll
.\sqldrivers\qsqlmysql.dll
.\sqldrivers\qsqlodbc.dll
.\sqldrivers\qsqlpsql.dll

.\translations\qt_ca.qm
.\translations\qt_cs.qm
.\translations\qt_de.qm
.\translations\qt_en.qm
.\translations\qt_fi.qm
.\translations\qt_fr.qm
.\translations\qt_he.qm
.\translations\qt_hu.qm
.\translations\qt_it.qm
.\translations\qt_ja.qm
.\translations\qt_ko.qm
.\translations\qt_lv.qm
.\translations\qt_pl.qm
.\translations\qt_ru.qm
.\translations\qt_sk.qm
.\translations\qt_uk.qm
```

Comment: Compare your `sql.db` directory in running with qt and without it. (relative address)

Comment: Do you have `Qt5Sql.dll` & `sqldrivers` folder with 4 dlls in it beside your execution directory?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I added all the files in the question.

Comment: Hm... I solved this problem by actualizing my version of QT by add remove programs, update all components...

Comment: I am glad your problem solved.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: hm... stil the same problem. But in this time I have another error:The procedure entry point toLatin1@QString@@QEGBA?AVQByteArray@@XZ could not be located in the dynamic link library. And QT update is no solution in this time. Anyone have any idea?